# Cassandra issue when counting millions of columns

Tags: java, cassandra

I was inserting columns to row, and by cassandra-cli checking qty of them:

`[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
492506 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
531375 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
556985 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
615568 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
740790 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
794993 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
1008291 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
1080951 columns
[default@CassandraExample] count admins[ascii('0')];
null`

and as you can see, later count printed null and now it prints null all the time(when I want to count admins[0]). I tried to resize max heap size to 1500M(I cant give more I don't know why(Java prints error)), and configure other options, but still it doesn't work.

What is possible cause of such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make a lot of educated guesses here:

- you're running a 32bit java, which is why you can't allocate more memory to its heap
- you're getting an error in Cassandra's system log
- you're not running Cassandra 1.0, which pages large count requests internally (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3068)

So my recommendations would be:

- Upgrade to 1.0 if you insist on doing huge counts, but
- Huge counts are never going to be fast, so consider using a [denormalized counter](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-0-8-part-2-counters) instead
- If you want to continue troubleshooting your old version, paste the exception from Cassandra's system.log and enable the debug switch on the cli

Comment: I thought I have java 64bit, but I appeared that I didn't... Thanks, installing Cassandra 1.0 and Java 64bit helped.

Comment: @jbellis, could you elaborate on the automatic paging of large count requests? issue 3068 refers to fixing CQL Count(*). Whenever I ask for Count(*) on a large request, it only returns 10000.